# Limit characters in input box to non-numbers only with Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive, ng-maxlength

I see that a lot of people are using directives to solve this problem which I find annoying.  While I like directives it feels like massive overkill.

I have an input

```
<input maxlength="4" type="text" id="CustomerNameKey" name="CustomerNameKey" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.customerNameKey" placeholder="Customer Name Key" required />
```

I thought the business requirement was just limit to 4 alphanumeric , so this code works great

```
maxlength="4"
```

However I cannot allow any number  ( so only allowing a-z / A-Z  )

Seems like I see

1. angular documentation with it throwing out warning to the page, but it is not restricting the input   I prefer to not allow more than 4 characters to be typed , and only alpha
2. all these directive solutions seem crazy to me
3. Any inline regex i can do?

Comment: What about `<input maxlength="4" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '')" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '')">`

Comment: I would bite the bullet and with angular  "When in Rome..."   do a directive  , here is a decent one    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230080/directive-to-allow-only-alphabetic-characters-in-view-and-model-value

Comment: If you don't like directives, it probably means you're not comfortable or familiar enough with them. They are very easy to write and intuitive once you understand them. It's worth the effort, especially for a simple problem such as this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the best approach is to use a directive. In fact, I just made one, you can see it in the jsFiddle

```
myApp.directive('smartInput', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        value: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
          if (event.key.search(/\d/g) != -1) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      },
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="value">'
    }
  }
]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28432/

**EDIT:**

HTML5 supports input checking in html `input` elements by use of the `pattern` attribute, although it does not respond in real time and must be used with a submit. If this is the functionality you are looking for, you can get away with a simple element:

```
<input type="text" name="charInput" pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="Not Numbers">
```

more information can be found on the [w3 page on the pattern attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp). Also noteworthy is the fact that this does not appear to be supported by safari